Reliably get TargetData for current process
In llvmlite, an instance of TargetData is required to get the ABI size of an object. This makes sense given that the size of an object is dependent on the word size and alignment. If I want to immediately compile and use the code in the current process, I shouldn't need anything other that the target data of the current process. The docs would seem to suggest that this would reliably get the target data for the current process.
import llvmlite.binding as llvm

# Initialize the LLVM
# https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/binding/examples.html
llvm.initialize()
llvm.initialize_native_target()
llvm.initialize_native_asmprinter()

target_string = llvm.get_process_triple()
target_data = llvm.create_target_data(target_string)

However, this last line aborts the Python process with the error:
LLVM ERROR: Unknown specifier in datalayout string

Aborted (core dumped)

Presumably, this is related to the fact that my process triple is x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu. I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo P53, so it shouldn't be that weird.
How do I get a working default TargetData for the current process?

Something is goofy with llvm.create_target_data. If you create a default target machine, you can get its TargetData and use that.
import llvmlite.binding as llvm

# Initialize the LLVM
llvm.initialize()
llvm.initialize_native_target()
llvm.initialize_native_asmprinter()

# Create a target machine representing the current host
target = llvm.Target.from_default_triple()
target_machine = target.create_target_machine()

# Extract the target data
target_data = target_machine.target_data

